# How long did the most difficult compound to synthesize last?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I heard that the most difficult compound to produce was a molecule that included Argon because it is a noble gas. I was wondering how long it was stable for.

Comment: \*coughs\*[Maitotoxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maitotoxin)\*coughs\*

Comment: @Jan.. just a few more months ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as *the* most difficult compound to produce. Instead, there are some hundreds of thousands of "stable" compounds of which we know pretty much **everything** - melting point, boiling point, heat capacity over a wide range of temperatures, refractive index, speed of sound, magnetic susceptibility, electrical conductivity, crystal structure, and many more. Around that field is a much wider "grey zone" of the not-so-stable compounds (**millions** of them), which miss some of these properties because they can't be measured.

As we reach out to the far outskirts of that zone, we meet more and more compounds with less and less known properties in each one, because they are increasingly frail and short-lived, to the point that the very words "produce" or "synthesize" (or even "exist", for that matter) do not quite apply to them anymore. Some of them last but a fraction of second; some live longer, but require very peculiar conditions. There is absolutely no meaningful way to arrange them in order of increasing "difficulty".

Also, welcome to Chem.SE.